# Sparklyr fill NA/NULL in spark dataframe

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I would like to assign NA/NULL in a spark data frame to its nearest neighbour. I came from R background so I uses sparklyr but can't figure out a way to do it.

Here is an example code:

```
 set.seed(1)    
 example <- data.frame (ID = 1:10, Cat = letters[1:5], 
                       Numb = sample(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1:10), 10))
     ID Cat Numb
  1   1   a   NA
  2   2   b    1
  3   3   c    3
  4   4   d    6
  5   5   e   NA
  6   6   a    5
  7   7   b    4
  8   8   c    9
  9   9   d   10
  10 10   e   NA
```

So I would like to fill Numb column, ID 1 NA to ID2 Numb 1, ID 5 to either id 4 and 6 (6 or 5), and ID 10 to ID 9 value (10). It can be done in R easily. Is there anyway to do it in Spark through Sparklyr?

Here is my R solution:

```
example$Numb1 <- example$Numb[c(1,1:(nrow(example)-1))]
example$Numb2 <- example$Numb[c(2:(nrow(example)), nrow(example))]
example$Merge <- ifelse(is.na(example$Numb), ifelse(is.na(example$Numb1), 
example$Numb2, example$Numb1), example$Numb)

    ID Cat Numb Numb1 Numb2 Merge
1   1   a   NA    NA     1     1
2   2   b    1    NA     3     1
3   3   c    3     1     6     3
4   4   d    6     3    NA     6
5   5   e   NA     6     5     6
6   6   a    5    NA     4     5
7   7   b    4     5     9     4
8   8   c    9     4    10     9
9   9   d   10     9    NA    10
10 10   e   NA    10    NA    10
```

Of course, things can get more complicated if I have multiple NA values in consecutive rows. Maybe another suggestion can be advised.

But for sparklyr, I have no clue what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partially working solution with a SQL query and a the `mutate` function from the `dplyr` package. It does not address the situation of multiple NA values in consecutive rows, since it's a translation of your base R solution, but it might be useful for other (more complete) approaches.

I've used the [Lag and Lead](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) functions of HiveQL in order to perform the "shifting" down and up of your column. It involves the creation of a new auxiliary Spark table (example2), which holds the "Numb1" and "Numb2" columns. Then, once the auxiliary table has been created, you can create the "Merged" column with `mutate`

```
library(DBI)
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)    
exampleDF <- data.frame (ID = 1:10, Cat = letters[1:5], 
                         Numb = sample(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1:10), 10))

# Connection to Spark and creation of the table to test.
sc <- spark_connect("local")
example <- copy_to(sc, exampleDF)  

# Create a Spark table with columns Numb1 and Numb2
DBI::dbSendQuery(sc, "CREATE TABLE example2 AS (SELECT ID, Cat, Numb, LAG(Numb, 1) over (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY ID) AS Numb1,
             LEAD(Numb, 1) over (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY ID) AS Numb2 FROM exampledf)")

# Load the auxiliary table as a Spark DataFrame
ex2 <- tbl(sc, "example2")

# Mutate in order to create the Merged column
res <- ex2 %>%
  mutate(Merged = ifelse(is.na(Numb), ifelse(is.na(Numb1), Numb2, Numb1), Numb))

res

# Source:   lazy query [?? x 6]
# Database: spark_connection
      id   cat  numb numb1 numb2 Merged
   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
 1     1     a    NA    NA     1      1
 2     2     b     1    NA     3      1
 3     3     c     3     1     6      3
 4     4     d     6     3    NA      6
 5     5     e    NA     6     5      6
 6     6     a     5    NA     4      5
 7     7     b     4     5     9      4
 8     8     c     9     4    10      9
 9     9     d    10     9    NA     10
10    10     e    NA    10    NA     10
```

As a side note, you can also avoid the use of the `mutate` function (and all the `ifelse`s) by means of the `COALESCE` function. I think this would be much more efficient.

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "SELECT ID, Cat, Numb, COALESCE(Numb, Numb1, Numb2) AS Merged FROM example2")
   ID Cat Numb Merged
1   1   a   NA      1
2   2   b    1      1
3   3   c    3      3
4   4   d    6      6
5   5   e   NA      6
6   6   a    5      5
7   7   b    4      4
8   8   c    9      9
9   9   d   10     10
10 10   e   NA     10
```

I hope this helps.

EDITED

If you want to avoid using SQL at all, you can do it also with `dplyr` functions:

```
example %>% arrange(ID) %>%
    mutate(Numb1 = lag(Numb, 1)) %>%
    mutate(Numb2 = lead(Numb, 1L)) %>%
    mutate(Merged = ifelse(is.na(Numb), ifelse(is.na(Numb1), Numb2, Numb1), Numb))
# Source:     lazy query [?? x 6]
# Database:   spark_connection
# Ordered by: ID
      ID   Cat  Numb Numb1 Numb2 Merged
   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
 1     1     a    NA    NA     1      1
 2     2     b     1    NA     3      1
 3     3     c     3     1     6      3
 4     4     d     6     3    NA      6
 5     5     e    NA     6     5      6
 6     6     a     5    NA     4      5
 7     7     b     4     5     9      4
 8     8     c     9     4    10      9
 9     9     d    10     9    NA     10
10    10     e    NA    10    NA     10
# ... with more rows
```

I had some trouble coding the two consecutive `mutate` functions (that's why I used a mixed SQL-dplyr approach in the first place). I ended up opening a [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/925) on sparklyr.

Comment: I think lag and lead is something most helpful! Thanks Jaime!